# Вопросы по вёрстке

Tags: ios, swift

Несколько вопросов про auto layout:
1. Что такое: Trailing Space to Safe Area, Top space to Safe Area, Leading Space to Safe Area, Bottom Space to Safe Area, Center Horizontally in Safe Area, Center Vertically in Safe Area. И на простых примерах я вроде как понял и заметил вот такие вещи:

Если сделать Center Horizontally in Safe Area и Center Vertically in Safe Area, тогда элементы будут правильно отображаться на всех устройствах. Leading Space to Safe Area - слева фиксирует, Trailing Space to Safe Area - справа фиксирует, расскажите по подробнее пожалуйста и возможно с примерами потому что пример с двумя кнопками и тд я делаю легко, а вот когда дело доходит до интерфейса более менее обычного, то сразу же куча ошибок

Answer (score 0):

Это слишком большая тема, чтобы раскрыть ее в небольшом тексте. Лучше почитать статьи, например:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/811496-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-getting-started